# How do I prove that a given point in a given subset of R^2 is an interior point?

Tags: general-topology, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

I need to show that the given point $(1, -3)$ in
$$D = \{(x, y): x>0 \space \mathrm{and} \space y \leq -2 \}$$
is an interior point of $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$. That is, $(1, -3) \in D^{\mathrm{o}}$. I understand that $(1, -3)$ is an interior point of $D$ if and only if there exists a positive real number $r > 0$ such that an open disk $B_r(1, -3)$ of radius $r > 0$ centered at $(1, -3)$, that is
$$B_r(1, -3) = \{ (x, y) : (x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 < r^2 \}$$
is a proper subset of $D$. That is, $B_r(1, -3) \subset D$. I also understand that in order to prove that $B_r(1, -3) \subset D$, I need to show that every arbitrary point $(x, y)$ in $B_r(1, -3)$ must also be in $D$, but $B_r(1, -3)$ can't be equal to $D$, since there is at least one point in $D$ that is not in $B_r(1, -3)$. How should I begin to word and write this proof?

Comment: Please, don't use unusual characters like ². They won't always render properly. Use `^2`.

Comment: The first step would be to figure out a suitable value of $r$. I would suggest plotting the set $D$, and the point $(1, 3)$. How far is this point from the boundary of $D$? After you figure out $r$, you can start with a set inclusion proof.

Comment: Also: you do not need to show *proper* containment. If you want proper containment, simply halve the radius of the ball.

Comment: Begin by trying to figure out what number the radius $r$ should be.

Comment: The trick is to how far out from $(1,-3)$ along the $x$ direction can I go before I start to get into trouble.  As $1> 0$ I can go a whole unit till I hit the edge.  So If $r < 1$ I can go all the way for $x=1$ to $x=1-r >0$ and still be above $0$. Likewise how far out can I go in the $y$ direction? Again if $r<1$ I can go all the way from $x=-3$ to $x=-3+r < -2$ and still be below $-2$.  Now those are the extreeeeeme attempts at stretching and the don't go far enough.  So $r=1$ ought to do it.  But what about all points?..... to be continued.

Comment: So you need to figure out a way to prove $(x-1)^2 + (y-3)^2 < r^2\implies x> 0$ and $y\ge 2$.  Do you see that that is exactly all you have to prove?  How do you do that?  Well here's a hint  $(x-1)^2 \le (x-1)^2 + (y-3)^2 < r^2\implies (x-1)^2 < r^2\implies |x-1| < r$.  Can you take it from there?  [That's why the stretching works.  If $(x,y)$ is within the critical event horizon of $(1,-3)$ then the $x$ value only is within bounds and the $y$ value alone is within bounds and so both are.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B_r(1, -3) = \{ (x, y) : (x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 < r^2 \}$

....

Okay.  If $(x,y) \in B_r(1,-3)$ then

$(x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 < r^2$.

But we know $(x-1)^2, (y+3)^2 > 0$

So $(x-1)^2 \le (x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 < r$ and $(y+3)^2 \le (x-1)^2 + (y+3)^2 < r$

And so $|x-1| < r$ and $|y+3| < r$.

So $-r < x-1 < r$ and $1-r < x < 1+r$.  And $-r < y+3 < r$ and $-3-r < y < -3+r$.

Now we *need* $x > 0$ but we have $x > 1-r$.  And we *need* $y+3 \le -2$ but we have $y < -3 + r$.

So now the question that arises is:  How small a value of $r$ do we need to assure that $x > 1-r \implies x > 0$ and that $y< -3+r \implies y \le -2$?

And we can note that if we ever have $x > 1-r > 0$ and $y< -3 + r \le -2$ we will be fine.  So we just need $1-r > 0$ and $-3+r \le -2$ or.....

Answer (score 0):

A simple drawing will convince you that $r = 1$ works. Algebraically: if $(x,y) \in B_1(1,-3)$ then $|x-1| < 1$ and $|y - (-3)| < 1$ (why?). The former implies $x > 0$ and the latter implies $y < -2$ as desired.